# Android user log in

Tags: android, android-activity, authentication

I am creating an application that lets the user log in to a profile they create, I just want to know how I would get a correct username and password entry to take the user to another activity as at the moment I just get errors if I try to use intent and startactivity.

```
public class Login extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

private EditText etUsername;
private EditText etPassword;
private Button btnLogin;
//private Button btnRegister;
private TextView lblResult;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);
    // Get the EditText and Button References
    etUsername = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditUsername);
    etPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditPassword);
    btnLogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login);
    //btnRegister = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
    lblResult = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lblmsg);


   // Button btnArrival = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
    //btnArrival.setOnClickListener(this);


// Set Click Listener
btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Check Login
        String username = etUsername.getText().toString();
        String password = etPassword.getText().toString();

        if(username.equals("User") && password.equals("user")){
            Intent i = new Intent();
            startActivity(i);
        } else {
            lblResult.setText("Login failed. Username and/or password doesn't match.");
        }
    }
});



    }

    public void onClick(View v)
    {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, UsersDbAdapter.class);
            startActivity(intent);
}

}
```

Comment: What are the errors? And it looks like you have 2 onclick listeners, but it's going to the first one (the anonymous one). Change `Intent i = new Intent();` to `Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, UsersDbAdapter.class);` and see if you're still getting errors. Just assuming without actually knowing what the errors are...

Comment: Just updated my comment above - hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you're only testing, as you compare both user and password to "user". But if they are equal, this code runs:

```
        Intent i = new Intent();
        startActivity(i);
```

That's a rather emtpy intent, isn't it? How what where why is there an activity started?
Somewhat lower, you're starting an activity like so:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, UsersDbAdapter.class);
        startActivity(intent);
```

That looks a lot better. It's got a context, and a class, so the startActivity knows what to do :)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have two onClick listeners? That might be the issue. Remove the btnLogin.setOnClickListener() call and make sure that android:onClick property of the button in your layout xml file it set to "onClick".

Comment: thanks guys took out the two onclicklistners and the 2nd intent call and that seems to be working now :)

Answer (score 0):

Also, instead of writing your own authentication class if you're only writing for Android devices, you might want to consider using [OpenID via Google App Engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/openid.html).